# Scale Video, Without 'ffmpeg Scaler' converting colorspace from RGBA to YUV

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, video-quality, color-correction, color

I have a video in RGBA space contained in MPNG codec. Which is in 4K. I need to Convert that into a 1080p File... SO i Used this -

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vcodec libx265 -vf scale=1920:1080 -sws_flags lanczos+accurate_rnd+full_chroma_inp+full_chroma_int -pix_fmt gbrp "x265GBRP.mkv"
```

> *But, I think ffmpeg converts rgb to yuv420p for scaling the
> footage.... I can See some **Artifacts** that **yuv420p** creates, like when
> you have Gradients... And also the **Color is WASHED OUT!** in output*

This Image was the ***Output:*** [image: image 1]

And this was the ***Input Frame:***[image: image 2]

***NOTE:*** As both the Files are in RGB ColorFormat.... My Video Decoder is Not the Problem.... (And these Images are Screenshots of Extracted frames from the Input and Output File)

DEBUG LOG - [txt File - GDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SMVtX9t4eaEbj_X2iUwCcbmqeu1waDKV/view?)

Something extra - [image: enHello]

Comment: Missing complete uncut debug log output of ffmpeg conversion.

Comment: Sir, I Updated It with the Log.. Is that What you meant with Debug Log Output, Sir?

Comment: no, i meant with "-v debug"

Comment: okay, Sir.. I am Doing that

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SMVtX9t4eaEbj_X2iUwCcbmqeu1waDKV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, There is a Way, I Can First Convert Those Images to RAW Video using "-vcodec png" with Scaling it.... Then I can encode that file